# regex negative lookahead not working

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I need a regex to search a string for M?' not followed by , or )

I think I need a negative lookahead, but I can't seem to get it working:

```
M?'(?!,|\))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Escape the `?`: `M\?'(?!,|\))` (or `M\?'(?![,)])`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `M\?'(?!,|\))`

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jG8qX7/1)**

Comment: @user1541301: No, it is not. `M\?'(?![,)])` is. And `M[?]'(?![,)])` is the most fail-safe.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Thanks for the enhancement.

Answer (score 1):

I believe `?` is part of search string so try following regex:

```
M\?'(?!,|\))
```

Comment: You've removed the `'` character from the search string?

Comment: Good catch @Marcus. I probably didn't saw it.

Answer (score 0):

```
M\?'(?![,\)])
_^
```

[See demo here](https://regex101.com/r/jG8qX7/2)